# How do I send generated encrypted password from C# to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

How do I encrypt the password in my register form and send it to mysql and after that I will go to my login form and enter the username and the password.
Show me some examples

```
string input_fname = textBox1.Text;
        string input_mname = textBox2.Text;
        string input_lname = textBox3.Text;
        string input_address = textBox6.Text;
        string input_age = textBox5.Text;
        string input_password = getMD5(textBox4.Text);

        // establishing connection
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.Server = "127.0.0.1";
        builder.UserID = "root";
        builder.Password = "seven7";
        builder.Database = "justsing";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ToString());
        connection.Open();

        // sql command
        string newuser_sql = "INSERT INTO `justsing`.`karaokeadmin` (`FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, `Address`, `Age`, `password`) VALUES (@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@Address,@Age,@password)";
        MySqlCommand newuser = new MySqlCommand(newuser_sql, connection);
        newuser.CommandText = newuser_sql;
        newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", input_fname);
        newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", input_mname);
        newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", input_lname);
        newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", input_address);
        newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", input_age);
        newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", input_password);
        newuser.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Inserted Succesfully");
    }
    public string getMD5(string text)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));
        byte[] result = md5.Hash;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            str.Append(result[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return str.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the login code on validation if it matches the username and password

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lname = textBox7.Text;
        string pass = textBox8.Text;
        if (lname == "" || pass == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields  Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
        }
        bool r = validate_login(lname, pass);
        if (r)
        {
            JustSingAdminControlPanel js = new JustSingAdminControlPanel();
            js.Show();
        }
        //code kung ano gustong buksan 
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Input");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us what exactly you have tried and where you are having a problem.

Comment: Start here, it's the beginning: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right

Comment: I tried using MD5 but then I read on some part of the stackoverflow MD5 cannot be decrypted ... it is a one-way hash

Comment: `I tried using MD5 but then I read on some part of the stackoverflow MD5 cannot be decrypted ... it is a one-way hash` you are doing it wrong. Read the article.

Comment: Im going to show my codes

Comment: The code you just updated with simply checks a database if a username and password combination exists. I'm guessing you're confused how to encrypt the password, but the thing is you want to hash, not encrypt, passwords. To validate, you hash the password given on login, and then ask the database for a combination of that username and hash.

Comment: Im sorry Im new here I already updated it

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function, such as MD5, is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to send it from the form to your API in cleartext (but using HTTPS, this is essential), then hash it on your backend (seperate issue how to do this), and finally save that hash in the MYSQL database. You do not want to encrypt passwords, you want to hash them.

Comment: You can read about md5 clsss here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Gianlucca Don't use MD5 - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: @smartis I had no idea about those exploits. Thank you!

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient , see the comment to the question.